# artisan not found when migrate with heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-artisan

I deployed the laravel app to heroku．
Running migrate gives me an error.

```
heroku run 'php artisan migrate' --app heroku-app-name
```

error

> Could not open input file: artisan

"ls" was executed to investigate the cause.

```
vagrant@homestead:~/code$ heroku run --app heroku-app-name "ls"
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.30.1 to 7.35.1.
Running ls on ⬢ heroku-app-name... up, run.1296 (Free)
Procfile  code  composer.json  index.php  vendor
```

The project is a laravel app. I think the difference in this directory is the cause of the error.
But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Why is the app under `code`? Normally its in the same directory as `composer.json`

Comment: @apokryfos This is certainly strange.
Before deploying it is in the code.
When investigating a solution, you may have done extra work.
Is this the cause?

Comment: It's likely this structure won't work without additional configuration i.e. modifying the `composer.json` psr-4 autoloader to load the App namespace from the `code` subdirectory and running `artisan` from the `code` subdirectory as well (since that's probably where it is now). I'm not sure if this directory structure change was intentional on your part or if it's something heroku did but I suggest trying to get the structure back to the default if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this:

*heroku run /app/php/bin/php /app/www/artisan migrate --app heroku-app-name*

In the above command, artisan file will be located at the root location of your Laravel project so replace '/app/www/artisan' by 'project root path'/artisan

Comment: Thank you
The site worked by organizing the directory